# how do I know if the number of inodes are already taken?

Tags: filesystems, storage, inode

According to what I have read here http://www.linux.org/article/view/intro-to-inodes, the inode structure occuppies 1% of the storage unit size. Besides, it may happen (if I recall correctly due to a huge amount of small files) that the space reserved for the inode structure fills up before the storage unit is completely filled.

How can I know if that's happening? Or how far is it to happen?

It's a question that came up while reading this article, and actually it may be the cause of an issue I'm having at work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can always compare the proportion of free blocks from

```
df -k
```

to the proportion of free inodes from

```
df -i
```

If the proportions are about the same, then you are using blocks and inodes at a ratio similar to the ratio that was planned when the filesystem was created. If the proportion of blocks used is much greater then you may run out of blocks before you run out of inodes. If the proportion of inodes is much greater then you may run out of inodes before you run out of blocks.

Answer (score 2):

@Celada's answer is of course correct. I just wanted to add that normally you don't really have to worry about the number of inodes, because the default settings reserve rather a lot of space for inodes. So you only need to be worried about that if you create a lot of very small files.

Take for example my /home directory, which is an ext4 file system. It has 184,518,716 1k blocks of space for data, and 11,722,752 inodes. That means that the inode space will only run out before the data space when you have more than 11 million files that are on average less than 16kB (184518716/11722752=15.74). Which is really a very unusual situation.